# handle_cast, multiple cores, and queues

Tags: erlang

Does Erlang take advantage of multiple cores when running a `gen_server`?  If I have a couple of different `handle_cast` in the `gen_server`, and they're called frequently, could they run in parallel?  I ask because, I have a design where one `handle_cast` enters data to a queue, and the other removes data from the same queue and processes it.  The queue is kept in the `gen_server` state.  A problem, as I see it, is that I must return a new queue (with the new item added, or with the retrieved item removed) when returning state.  If these are running in parallel then it seems that race conditions or inconsistencies can develop in the queue.  Is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. A `gen_server` runs in a single Erlang process. A single process can't be broken down into multiple activities that can be run concurrently.